# GetSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false) не работает

Tags: actionbar, android

Доброго времени суток.
Как удалить кнопку назад из actionbar ?

Comment: у меня та же проблема, только во фрагменте не получается кнопку назад установить вместо "сандвича".

Answer (score 1):

```
actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false);
actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);
```

Answer (score 0):

`actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false)`

Comment: увы не помогает